# 6 wire doorbell chime installation with Google Nest doorbell

Tags: doorbell

I'm trying to install a Google Nest doorbell. I opened up the doorbell chime, and it looks nothing like the diagrams I've found online. I have no clue how to install the chime connector, which is supposed to be the first step of installation.

Currently there is a working front and back doorbell.

Please see the diagram below:

[image]

There are 6 wires total: 3 white, 3 black. There are 4 screws, labeled 0, 1, 2, and T. The 3 white wires are all going to 0.

Any help would be appreciated in knowing how to install this, or just knowing what the screw numbers mean. Thanks!

Comment: Are there multiple buttons that activate the bell?

Comment: There's one for the front, and one for the back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does your doorchime do a ding-dong for one door, and a dong for the other door? If so, it looks very similar to the wiring here:

[image: Wiring Diagram]

[Friedland Doorbell Manual](https://www.tlc-direct.co.uk/Technical/DataSheets/Friedland/230.pdf)

0 (top left) is common and not connected to anything inside the chime

T or 3 is transformer (which Google Nest may call TRANS)

1 is push for door 1 (which Google Nest may call FRONT)

[image]

2 is push for door 2 (or REAR, leave this wire connected to 2)

https://support.google.com/googlenest/answer/9247327?hl=en

Comment: Good find on that manual - I've added an image of the wiring diagram inline with your answer incase that PDF link dies in the future.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this and get back to you to see if it worked later today

Comment: So I dont touch anything to do with 0 and 2, correct?

Comment: I don't think so, but I can't guarantee that your doorchime is the same.

Comment: Thanks for the diagram. The front happened to be 2 and the rear was 1. However there is another problem: the voltage isn't high enough for the Google Nest. This is a different issue though, I'll mark your answer as correct

Comment: Thank you. I think Google Nest vary in their voltage requirements, door chimes are pretty tolerant so you may be able to change the transformer to one that works with Nest and the chime still work.